# Composite Foreign Key a part of the Composite Primary Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a two following 2 models in an MVC project:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RiskDotNet.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string SrcSys { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public string CustId { get; set; }
        public string CustNm { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RiskDotNet.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Customer"), Column(Order = 0)]
        public string SrcSys { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Customer"), Column(Order = 1)]
        public string CustId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public string AccId { get; set; }
        public string BrId { get; set; }
        public string ProdId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Balance> Balances { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `Customer` can be identified by the Composite Key Source System (`SrcSys`) & Customer ID (`CustId`). While the `Account` can be identified by Source System (`SrcSys`), Customer ID (`CustId`) plus Account Id (`AccId`). But the second model is not allowing me use of another Column.

Please see if any of you experts can help.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Duplicate 'Column' attribute at the lines of Foreign Keys with Column being underlined,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find specifying composite key (both PK and FK) much easier to understand and less error prone by using fluent API configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Customers) // the property should really be called Customer, currently it sounds like collection
    .WithMany(e => e.Accounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.SrcSys, e.CustId }); // <= the composite FK
```

But if you prefer data annotations, just apply the `ForeignKey` attribute on the *navigation property* and provide a comma separated list with the FK property names:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string SrcSys { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CustId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string AccId { get; set; }
    public string BrId { get; set; }
    public string ProdId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Balance> Balances { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SrcSys,CustId")] // <= the composite FK
    public virtual Customer Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, However, correct me if I am wrong, I guess in the code for data annotations you forgot to comment out the two earlier ForeignKey lines I had incorrectly inserted and the single line of composite key would be enough.

Comment: For data annotations - yes, I've already corrected that. For fluent API - you have to define `one-to-many`relationship configuration in order to get `HasForeignKey` method available.